# Removing rows by group and based on values

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
data 
ID               Application                 Admission
1                FALSE                       FALSE
2                FALSE                       FALSE
2                TRUE                        FALSE
3                FALSE                       FALSE
3                TRUE                        FALSE
3                TRUE                        TRUE
```

I want to somehow group the rows by ID and then remove everything but the last row for that ID. It would look like this:

```
ID               Application                 Admission
1                FALSE                       FALSE
2                TRUE                        FALSE
3                TRUE                        TRUE
```

I'm fairly new to coding so I just went one by one and removed rows individually. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: [Already answered, you can visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: @Amy That answer is in MySQL, CarolynGrace is asking for an R solution

Comment: If you use the data.table package and convert it to a data.table, there's `unique(data, by="ID", fromLast = TRUE)` (seeing if I can find a dupe...)

Comment: @divi & Rich - There are answers to this question (like Wen's) that don't apply to the first & last one you linked, so not a great dupe. Neither is the one I added, though (which is specifically about data.table)...

Comment: A slight variation of a data.table answer -                                      `setDT(data)`                                                                              `setkey(data,ID)`
`data[J(unique(ID)),mult="last"]`

Answer (score 2):

From base R

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID,fromLast = T),]
  ID Application Admission
1  1       FALSE     FALSE
3  2        TRUE     FALSE
6  3        TRUE      TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(n())
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Application Admission
  <int>       <lgl>     <lgl>
1     1       FALSE     FALSE
2     2        TRUE     FALSE
3     3        TRUE      TRUE
```